# Is posting the problem as an image acceptable?

Tags: discussion

Sometime people posts question (or answer) by uploading a piece of paper, sometimes handwritten, that states the problem / solutions.

See for example [fence a circular land and a square land.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791927/fence-a-circular-land-and-a-square-land))

One question even posted a link to a video and said "I don't understand around minute 40:33" ([Pigeon hole principle application](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611006/pigeon-hole-principle-application))

Now, is this acceptable?

It surely is harder to decypher a handwritten paper, it cannot be searched over, and in general is worse than latex.

The video thing is even worse; Now nobody will know what the problem is about until they go to the video and listen to it; this effectively makes the question useless for anyone but the original poster. It's not the way math.se is supposed to be used, I think.

On the other hand, though, when I flagged the video question for "very low quality", it got disputed, so obviously there is not consensus about this.

What are your thoughts, and why should it be allowed / why not?

Comment: Does [«What should I do when I see a "pic-question"?»](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13677/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-pic-question) answer your question?

Comment: ...or maybe better [«On the inclusion of pages-of-text-as-images in questions»](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/) (but cf. [«Are pictures of hand-written drawings allowed?»](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12289))

Comment: I can assure you posting a link to video with time stamp is not the worse. There are people who post a link to a video as question without telling anyone which part of video he/she is referring to.